# Configurar nginx para receber qualquer dominio

Tags: servidor, nginx

Possuo essa configuração no *nginx* que qualquer domínio que é apontado no meu servidor ele acessa a pasta com o nome domínio.

Minha dúvida é como faço para que meus clientes possam apontar o domínio dele para o meu servidor só que em uma pasta só.

Exemplo: meu site é `www.meudominio.com,`  quando ele apontar para o meu site ele acessa a URL amigável dele tipo `www.meudominio.com/user`, como se fosse um serviço de loja virtual tipo o *hostgator*, desde já agradeço a ajuda!

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/$domain;
    port_in_redirect off;
    index index.html index.php;
    location / {
        charset utf-8;
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;       
        }
    }   
    location /url/ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /url/index.php?url=$1 last;      
        }
    }   
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)  {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return      444;
        }
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT 80;
    }
}
```

Comment: Em que parte o que fez não funciona? Parece certo.

Comment: Acredito que eles vão ter que fazer um alias (CNAME) no DNS do domínio deles para o seu domínio.
Segue um exemplo no Registro.br. [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS4Rs.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS4Rs.png).